# Sign of a multiple integral involving multiple exponential functions

Tags: integration, functions, exponential-function

I am working on a research project (math bio), and I found that the sign of an expression depends on a multiple integral $I$ defined below. $I$ involves plenty of nested undefined functions. I conjecture that $I<0$, but do not manage to properly determine the sign of $I$.

Given:

- an increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ with $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(x) = +\infty$,
- an increasing function $g:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ with $g(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} g(x) = +\infty$,
- an increasing function $h:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ with $h(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} h(x) = +\infty$,

The multiple integral $I$ is defined as:

$I=\int_{x=0}^{+\infty} \int_{y=0}^{+\infty}  e^{-f(x)}  e^{-f(y)} \left(e^{-g(x)}-e^{-g(y)} \right) \left( 1-e^{-h(x)} \right) \text{d}x\text{d}y$

Could you help me determining the sign of $I$?

Thank you.

Comment: Dear all, I edited my question to provide additional context. Would it be possible to reopen it?

Comment: I think there's a lot missing here. For instance, you can pick functions $f,g$ like $\log(x+1)$ so the integral doesn't even exist - you should probably exclude this. Your conjecture that $h<0$ is wrong, too - taking $f(x)=\log(x^2+1)$ and $f(x)=x$, for instance. This question is definitely salvageable, but I don't think it's there yet.

Comment: Thank you, KReiser. This helps a lot. Actually in the full expression, this integral is found within another integral ($\int_{x=0}^{+\infty} e^{-f(x)} (1-e^{-m(x)})h(x) dx$) that seems to be negative (with $m$ being another function with the same properties as $f$ and $g$). This is the sign of this integral that I would like to determine; but I wrongly conjectured that $h<0$.

Comment: How come the integral does not exist for $f$ and $g$ defined as $log(x+1)$? In that case, we get $h(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{y-x}{(y+1)^2(x+1)} dy$, right?

Comment: You gotta put all the relevant details in the post, otherwise you're not going to get a good answer. And that integral that you wrote down doesn't converge - the indefinite integral of that is $\frac{\log(y+1)}{x+1} +\frac{1}{y+1}+c$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is the post clearer now?